# orderColumn for sorting not working in yajra datatable using in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, datatables

OrderColumn not working for sorting the list according to updated_at but not working.

This is my code you can see

```
$product = Product::query()->get();

return Datatables::of($product )
            ->orderColumn('updated_at', 'DESC')
            ->make(true);
```

Javascript code

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var columns = [
                { 
                    data: 'name', 
                    name: 'name', 
                    searchable: true 
                },
            columns.push({
                    data: 'action', 
                    name: 'action',                      
                    orderable: false,
                    searchable: "false",
                    className: "text-center"
                });
            $('#product-table').DataTable({  
                pageLength: 25,              
                processing: true,
                serverSide: true,                                                 
                ajax: {
                    url: '{{ route('products.dt') }}',
                },
                columns: columns,
            });                                                           
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: @kamleshPaul you can see my code I have upload

Comment: @kamleshPaul bro...It's Not working

Comment: Bro... latest() getting according to created_at column base  I want to according to updated_at column base listing

Comment: Also, It's not working

Comment: $kamlesh Paul bro... If ``$product = Product::query()->orderBy('updated_at', 'DESC');`` I'm using this then sorting correctly but datatable not working...

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that JQuery Datatables is performing its own sort after receiving the data.
So the sort on the server is ignored.

I have run into the same issue, but have not yet found a solution.
I am thinking about adding an extra hidden column to sort the data, but this is not a great solution either.